# query does not return id attribute

Tags: laravel-5.5

i want to show a job post. in jobposts controller i coded:

```
public function show(JobPost $JobPost)
    {
        //
        if (Auth::check()) {
            $JobPost = JobPost::find($JobPost->id);

        $CvFolders = $JobPost->CvFolders;

        return view('JobPosts.show', [
            'JobPost' => $JobPost,
            'cvFolders' => $CvFolders
        ]);
    }
}
```

and this is my jobpost model

```
  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class JobPost extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'job_posts';

    protected $fillable = [
        'company_id',
        'user_id',
        'title',
        'summary',
        'description',
        'requirements',
        'benefits',
        'approval',
        'location',
        'publish_date',
        'expiration_date'
    ];

    public function User()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
    }
    public function Company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Company', 'company_id');
    }
    public function CvFolders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\CvFolder');
    }
```

i get the error: "Trying to get property of non-object"

when i looked for the reason i realized that the ($JobPost -> id) returns null. 
when i did: dd $JobPost, i saw that it returns all other attributes of the job post but the id. 
and my IDE says the referenced field has not been found

Comment: Do you even need to do the `JobPost::find($JobPost->id);`? Laravel will resolve the provided id-parameter for the show method automatically if there is a model with that id. Can you dd the JobPost right which is passed into the method show?

Comment: @Tamali
when i dd the $JobPost it returns a json that starts like this
 #table: "job_posts"
  #fillable: array:11 [▶]
  #connection: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
there is no id field in $fillable

Comment: Are you sure its a json and not a JobPost-Object? Did you try dd the result of `$JobPost->CsvFolders` on the same JobPost-Object? ( It is convention to use lowerCamelCase for Variables and methods in PHP by the way )

Comment: @Tamali i deleted  JobPost::find($JobPost->id)  now it returns $jobposts null to the view. but if i dd $jobpost at the controller it returns the job post

Comment: Sorry, im confused. The variable that is passed into the method is called `$JobPost` or `$jobposts`? If you pass the variable to the view like this `'JobPost' => $jobPost` then it will be reachable within the view with the name on the key-side of the array as a variable. So in that case `$JobPost`.